# Ignoring non-serializable type in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am using JSON.NET in an ASP.NET MVC application. In one of my filters I am serializing action-arguments using JSON.NET:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actionContext.ActionArguments);
```

But this sometimes throws an error. How can I check whether an object in action-argument is serializable or not and ignore it if it is not-serializable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can query if any of the properties have a `NonSerialized` attribute.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, trying isserializable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable.aspx

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, what do you think by `var args = actionContext.ActionArguments.Where(a => a.Value != null && a.Value.GetType().IsSerializable); JsonConvert.SerializeObject(args)`

Comment: What is the error being thrown?  Json.Net does not require objects to have a `Serializable` attribute on them.

Comment: I am getting exception that says that not able to serialize?

Comment: On a basic POCO checking a.Value.GetType().IsSerializable would return false but would serialize just fine using the OP's code.